# CosmosDB Invalid BSON With Update using $

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following Document (I am using Microsoft's Azure Cosmos for MongoDB)

```
db.polls.find({ _id: ObjectId("59ee64038c3a482200a08dbc")})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ee64038c3a482200a08dbc"),
    "title" : "Lunch Games",
    "options" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59ee64038c3a482200a08dbd"),
            "text" : "7 Wonders",
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59ee64038c3a482200a08dbe"),
            "text" : "Acquire",
            "votes" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59ee66fa99ea5912bc483cc1"),
            "text" : "Testing 1234",
            "votes" : 1
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 1
}
```

What I hoped to do is increment the votes integer by when with a the `findOneAndUpdate` call. The call that I am attempting to use is

```
db.polls.findOnAndUpdate({
        _id: ObjectId("59ee64038c3a482200a08dbc"),
        "options.text" : "7 Wonders" 
    }, 
    {
        $inc : {'options.$.votes' : 1}
    });
```

From what I understand about the `$` positional operator it will select the first item that matches the find part of the query and perform the operation on that element. What I receive from the application is the following exception

```
MongoError: Invalid BSON field name 'options.$.votes'
at Function.MongoError.create (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:497:72
at authenticateStragglers (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:443:16)
at Connection.messageHandler (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:477:5)
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:331:22)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:548:20)
```

When I replace the `$` with `0` for example the query succeeds and updates the vote for the first item.

Comment: CosmosDB is not MongoDB. Things that work perfectly on MongoDB do not necessarily work with CosmosDB. If you want to use CosmosDB then I suggest using it's own native API rather than a MongoDB emulation. If you want to use MongoDB code, then use MongoDB instead. It is not "Azure Cosmos for MongoDB". They are **completely different products** and are not the same software. The distinction should be clearer than Azure is actually presenting it.

Comment: Well clearly that distinction was muddied significantly, the Data Explorer and other features of Azure Reference MongoDB shell and queries, making it seem like it is running a MongoDB back-end. I appreciate the quick response, and hopefully this will aid others in preventing further confusion.